# How to profile an ASP.NET web service on a remote server by EQATEC profiler?

Tags: profiler, eqatec

I am thinking the modified dlls will create a log file some where in the remote system so I can open it later after load test but all I found was a log file in $(SystemRoot)\Temp\EQATECProfilerLogs saying nothing other than app started. Do I need to install EQATEC profiler on the remote server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This scenario is adressed in [this EQATEC forum thread](http://forum.eqatec.com/default.aspx?g=posts&m=1490#post1490):

A profiled app needs to be told when we want it to produce its profiling report. For plain apps this is simple and has therefore been automated: when Main exits. But your web-service has no similar "exit point" - it just keeps on running until you kill it.

Therefore you have to explicitly/manually tell the profiled web-service to take a snapshot. The easiest way is to simply run the profiler on the same machine as the web-service is running on: when the web-service is starting up it will automatically connect to the profiler and you can then run your tests and control/dump timing info at will using the "take snapshot" and "clear counters"-buttons.

Alternatively, you can make a reference to the supplied runtime-module from within your code and make explicit calls to the API (TakeSnapshot etc) precisely where you want in your code. The runtime-modules reside in C:\Program Files\EQATEC\EQATECProfiler\RuntimeDLL.

Comment: I cannot mark your reply as answer because I moved on with different task and cannot verify the solution. But the explanation sounds reasonable so I upvoted it.

Comment: No worries. And sorry for not answering your question earlier. We respond pretty quickly to topics in our eqatec forum, but stackoverflow postings sometimes goes unnoticed.